# Paste multi line code in elm-repl

Tags: elm

I'm just trying to evaluate some expressions in elm-repl but I don't know how to paste it in.

Something like:

```
List.map
            (\l ->
                li []
                    [ span [ class "position filled" ]
                        []
                    ]
            )
            [ 1, 2, 3 ]
```

Answer (score 4):

You can span multiple lines in Elm REPL by ending each line with a backslash (`\`) character:

```
List.map \
        (\l -> \
            li [] \
                [ span [ class "position filled" ] \
                    [] \
                ] \
        ) \
        [ 1, 2, 3 ]
```

Comment: That's quite poor. That means I cannot copy multiline code from my editor and paste it in the REPL.